# Save all the terminal output to a file

Tags: terminal, output

Is there some way of saving all the terminal output to a file with a command?

- I'm not talking about redirection `command > file.txt`
- Not the history `history > file.txt`, I need the full terminal text
- Not with hotkeys !

Something like `terminal_text > file.txt`

Comment: [A possible duplicate](http://askubuntu.com/questions/161935/how-do-i-log-all-input-and-output-in-a-terminal-session), anyways thanks :)

Comment: Many GUI terminal emulators allow to save the scroll buffer, but this is not accessible to commands (leaving aside `xdotool` and this sort of black art).

Comment: Try Terminal menu -> Shell -> Export text as, like here: http://www.mactricksandtips.com/2013/04/save-terminals-text-output.html

Comment: tee is a good alternative if you can't get script to work

Answer (score 141, accepted):

You can use `script`. It will basically save everything printed on the terminal in that `script` session.

From [`man script`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/script.1.html):

```
script makes a typescript of everything printed on your terminal. 
It is useful for students who need a hardcopy record of an 
interactive session as proof of an assignment, as the typescript file 
can be printed out later with lpr(1).
```

You can start a `script` session by just typing `script` in the terminal, all the subsequent commands and their outputs will all be saved in a file named `typescript` in the current directory. You can save the result to a different file too by just starting `script` like:

```
script output.txt
```

To logout of the `script` session (stop saving the contents), just type `exit`.

Here is an example:

```bsh
$ script output.txt
Script started, file is output.txt

$ ls
output.txt  testfile.txt  foo.txt

$ exit
exit
Script done, file is output.txt
```

Now if I read the file:

```bsh
$ cat output.txt

Script started on Mon 20 Apr 2015 08:00:14 AM BDT
$ ls
output.txt  testfile.txt  foo.txt
$ exit
exit

Script done on Mon 20 Apr 2015 08:00:21 AM BDT
```

`script` also has many options e.g. running quietly `-q` (`--quiet`) without showing/saving program messages, it can also run a specific command `-c` (`--command`) rather than a session, it also has many other options. Check [`man script`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/script.1.html) to get more ideas.

Comment: Can it be invoked after the fact? (i.e. At the end of a session) Or does it have to be invoked before the content you want logged?

Comment: @tjt263 It has to be invoked before the contents you want to be saved..

Comment: Damn. That's a shame. I don't usually know I want it until afterwards.

Comment: @tjt263 you could put it inside your .bashrc and append everything into /tmp.

Comment: To export it retroactively, try Terminal menu -> Shell -> Export text as, like here: mactricksandtips.com/2013/04/save-terminals-text-output.html

Comment: Thanks. This saved my day. But I had to use `script -c "rails runner -e development lib/scripts/my_script.rb" report.txt`
because just using `script` then ran the `rails runner` in script session didn't wrote everything in the output file. Reference: https://askubuntu.com/a/715798/428475

Comment: @Magne you should note in your comment that it is specific to the terminal utility in Mac. gnome-terminal, for one, does not have that menu, so we should assume that other linux terminal windows won't have it either.

Comment: @maxweel thanks for pointing that out. I cannot edit my comment now, but I think your comment serves as that note now.

Answer (score 24):

I too faced the same problem and after some search came up with this solution:

Add to your `.bash_aliases` this:

```bsh
# Execute "script" command just once
smart_script(){
    # if there's no SCRIPT_LOG_FILE exported yet
    if [ -z "$SCRIPT_LOG_FILE" ]; then
        # make folder paths
        logdirparent=~/Terminal_typescripts
        logdirraw=raw/$(date +%F)
        logdir=$logdirparent/$logdirraw
        logfile=$logdir/$(date +%F_%T).$$.rawlog

        # if no folder exist - make one
        if [ ! -d $logdir ]; then
            mkdir -p $logdir
        fi

        export SCRIPT_LOG_FILE=$logfile
        export SCRIPT_LOG_PARENT_FOLDER=$logdirparent

        # quiet output if no args are passed
        if [ ! -z "$1" ]; then
            script -f $logfile
        else
            script -f -q $logfile
        fi

        exit
    fi
}

# Start logging into new file
alias startnewlog='unset SCRIPT_LOG_FILE && smart_script -v'

# Manually saves current log file: $ savelog logname
savelog(){
    # make folder path
    manualdir=$SCRIPT_LOG_PARENT_FOLDER/manual
    # if no folder exists - make one
    if [ ! -d $manualdir ]; then
        mkdir -p $manualdir
    fi
    # make log name
    logname=${SCRIPT_LOG_FILE##*/}
    logname=${logname%.*}
    # add user logname if passed as argument
    if [ ! -z $1 ]; then
        logname=$logname'_'$1
    fi
    # make filepaths
    txtfile=$manualdir/$logname'.txt'
    rawfile=$manualdir/$logname'.rawlog'
    # make .rawlog readable and save it to .txt file
    cat $SCRIPT_LOG_FILE | perl -pe 's/\e([^\[\]]|\[.*?[a-zA-Z]|\].*?\a)//g' | col -b > $txtfile
    # copy corresponding .rawfile
    cp $SCRIPT_LOG_FILE $rawfile
    printf 'Saved logs:\n    '$txtfile'\n    '$rawfile'\n'
}
```

And to the end of your `.bashrc` file add this:

```
smart_script
```

After you've done this, "script" command will be executed once in every terminal session, logging everything to `~/Terminal_typescripts/raw`.

If you want, you can save current session log *after the fact* *(in the end of the session)* by typing `savelog` or `savelog logname` – this will copy current raw log to `~/Terminal_typescripts/manual` and also create readable .txt log in this folder. 
(If you forget to do so, raw log files will still be in their folder;
you'll just have to find them.) 
Also you may start recording to a new log file by typing `startnewlog`.

There will be a lot of junk log files, but you can clean old ones from time to time, so it's not a big problem.

(Based on https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-terminal/+question/7131 , https://askubuntu.com/a/493326/473790 )

Comment: Why do you need the 'exit' command after you started the logging?

Comment: Seems like calling "script" command from the .bash_profile on Mac OSX has some strange effect on the shell. Do you know if this should work on OSX?

Comment: @Danijel can you describe "some strange effect" you mentioned? This would help others to help you.

Comment: I can't remember any more :-(, sorry.

Comment: @Danijel The "exit" command is needed because if you don't, you'll have to type exit (or ctlr+d) twice in every terminal tab you have open, instead of the normal once.  The first exit will exit the "script" session, and the second will exit your bash session and close the terminal tab (if you have auto-close enabled upon exit).

Comment: Any solution about using vim (or some another interactive editor or alike) fills the log file with a lot of junk?

Comment: @kakigadol Im wondering the same.. did u find any solution to this issue? alexpad maybe some input on this?

Comment: yes, I found a great project named asciinema it solves most of the problems https://asciinema.org/

Answer (score 4):

In the following steps, run `xrdb ~/.Xressources` after modifying the X-resources file, then open a new terminal to test the changes.

### XTerm

**Mouse:** Hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Left-mouse-click</kbd>. The "Main Options"
menu shows up.
Select "Print-All Immediately" and release. An `XTerm[date]` file with the
terminal contents has been created in your home directory.

**Keyboard shortcut**: To bind the action to
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>y</kbd>, add to your `~/.Xresources` file:

```
XTerm*vt100.Translations: #override\
    Ctrl Shift <Key> y: print-immediate()
```

**Setting the path**: `printFileImmediate` sets the prefix of the dumped file.
Useful to specify the path of the dumped file. For example, to dump
`/home/user/dumps/xt[date]` files,

```
XTerm*printFileImmediate: /home/user/dumps/xt
```

### Urxvt

**Keyboard shortcut**: Include in `~/.Xresources`:

```
URxvt.print-pipe: cat > $HOME/scrollback
```

Binds to <kbd>Ctrl+Print</kbd> or <kbd>Shift+Print</kbd>.

### Other terminals

Not all of them can do it; check their manual page or menu options.

Beyond `script`, a terminal-agnostic solution is to use a multiplexer.

In Tmux, it's a matter of running its internal command

```
capture-pane -S - ; save-buffer scrollback-file
```

This in `.tmux.conf` would bind it to <kbd>Ctrl+b</kbd><kbd>Ctrl+s</kbd>:

```
bind C-s capture-pane -S - \; save-buffer $HOME/scrollback
```

Answer (score 2):

[nhi](https://github.com/strang1ato/nhi) will perfectly solve your problem. This tool automatically captures all potentially useful information about each executed command (as well as its output).

With `nhi` you can easily retrieve any shell session (or terminal output) in its entirety, or only a part of shell session, by using an advanced querying mechanism provided by `nhi`.

You can think of `nhi` as a greatly enhanced `history`.

**Note:**

I am the creator of this tool. If you have questions, please feel free to ask.

Comment: I am looking for something like this but I used `cygwin`, `MacOS`, and `Ubuntu`. I would like to try this on Ubuntu but can you elaborate on what changes you made to `bash`? Is it possible to use it with stock bash with limited functionality?

Comment: @MiserableVariable Bash and zsh binaries since ubuntu 21.04 are for some reason stripped from variable addresses which are required by nhi.  I didn't change bash and zsh binaries at all. My bash and zsh binaries are exactly the same as in other distros (ubuntu made some unusual changes to their binaries).

Answer (score 0):

For xfce4-terminal use the accels.scm file.

For instance, to reassign Ctrl-Shift-s from 'set title' to 'save contents'
Open to edit: ~/.config/xfce4/terminal/accels.scm

Then search for 'save-contents' and modify the line as follows:

```
(gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/terminal-window/save-contents" "<Primary><Shift>s")

    ; This will map 'save the entire scrollback buffer to a file' to the Left_Ctrl-Shift-s keystrokes.

; NOTE: commented lines start with a ;
```

xfce4-terminal has a menu layout similar to the mac terminal answer above. Within an xfce4-terminal select 'Terminal, Save contents..' or simply Left_Ctrl-Shift-s.

A filemanager will open to allow you to select where to save the file containing the screen buffer output.