# How to store serial console output to a file locally, without a serial cable

Tags: io-redirection, serial-console

I am running embedded Linux and my command line has `console=/dev/ttyO0,...`. I have terminal program connected to this UART and can see *everything* produced by the system.

Now, when running in the field, I want to store all this output in the file (I have the media connected). But all my efforts using `syslogd`, `klogd`, `logger` and Co. do not give me the desired result - some messages are stored, but some are not - usually the most important.

For example, if I run:

```shell
myapplication.sh | logger
```

`echo` commands I see in `syslog`, `print`s from the application too, some drivers messages too. But if the application crashes with segmentation fault this info is not logged. But this is most valuable!

So, the best and most desired is to redirect `ttyO0` to a file, but how?

I found such a recommendation:

```bash
(stty raw; cat > received.txt) < /dev/ttyO0
```

but this doesn't work: I can type a command, e.g. `ifconfig`, but reply does not appear neither in the file nor on console. Even the file is not created...:-(

If it is possible to have both - file and serial console - it will be brilliant. But file has higher priority.

Many thanks for a help!

**Update** I found a solution and have added it in the answer section.

Comment: Please have a look at https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/200642/254422

Comment: Thank you, benarista, but this doesn't work. At least kernel messages from drivers are not stored. Also running "script" from script is problematic - it exits arbitrary or produces empty files. But major problem - kernel messages are not stored.

Comment: Dear Benarista, how can I start "script" command from within a bash script? It does nothing and hangs when I do this.

Comment: Starting "script -a -f" in background makes my script to run, but the log contains only i/o from console, not from the script itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I think I found the answer. I am very very surprised that such a simple and required IMHO thing is solved in so "irregular" way, but this is the life...:-)
Anyway, thanks to `telcoM` who gave me the references which lead to references and more references and finally allowed to find the `ttyrpl` package which does exactly what I wanted.
The package maintaining stopped some 7-10 years ago and it took me some time to adopt it to my Linux version and required libraries, but it work!
It does exactly what I wanted - collects the outputs of ttyS0/ttyO0 and stores it to a file. And has a lot of fancy options although I don't need them...:-)

Answer (score 4):

You seem to have missed one fairly basic fact. Every pipeable program relies on the fact that it gets **three** standard file descriptors in a pre-opened state from whatever program invokes it. In most cases involving pipes, the invoking program will be the command shell.

These three file descriptors are:

- file descriptor #0: standard input stream, or `stdin` for short.
- file descriptor #1: standard output stream, or `stdout` for short.
- file descriptor #2: standard **error output** stream, or `stderr` for short.

When a program is not being piped or redirected to read/write a file, then all these three file descriptors will usually point to a TTY device the current login session is running on. If a program is deliberately started as a daemon or a background/non-interactive process, all of these might be directed to file(s) or `/dev/null`, or possibly into some sort of logging facility.

Error messages are normally output into the `stderr` stream, precisely so that they won't get mixed in with the possibly-piped data output. But in cases like your, when you wish to capture **all** the output, you need to explicitly tell the system to grab both streams.

If you want to pass all the output from your `myapplication.sh` into a pipe, you might have to do something like this:

```
myapplication.sh 2>&1 | logger
```

The `2>&1`says "redirect file descriptor #2 to the same place #1 is going", and then you can pipe both of them at once.

You can test it yourself with a little script like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "this is stdout"
echo "this is stderr" >&2
```

The `>&2` means "take the standard output of this command and send it into the standard error stream instead". This is probably the easiest way to generate `stderr` output in a script.

Now, if you run this script like `./test.sh | od -t x1z` to get its output in hex-dumped form, you'll get this:

```
$ ./test.sh | od -t x1z
this is stderr
0000000 74 68 69 73 20 69 73 20 73 74 64 6f 75 74 0a     >this is stdout.<
0000017
```

So only the `stdout` output got processed by the `od`command.

If you add the `2>&1` to merge both streams, you'll get this instead:

```
$ ./test.sh 2>&1 | od -t x1z
0000000 74 68 69 73 20 69 73 20 73 74 64 6f 75 74 0a 74  >this is stdout.t<
0000020 68 69 73 20 69 73 20 73 74 64 65 72 72 0a        >his is stderr.<
0000036
```

Now both outputs were sent into the pipeline, which is what you want in your case with `| logger`.

---

Your second command line is capturing whatever your embedded device is receiving from the terminal program, not what the embedded device is sending to the terminal:

```
(stty raw; cat > received.txt) < /dev/ttyO0
```

You said you're working on an embedded system that uses the kernel parameter `console=/dev/ttyO0`, so essentially `/dev/console` will be a serial port, not a graphical display (which may not even exist in an embedded device).

If you are running that command on the embedded device, the commands inside the parentheses will run with their *standard input stream* (file descriptor #0, or `stdin` for short) assigned to `/dev/ttyO0`. But if you are entering that command over the serial line connected to `ttyO0`, that's what it's probably going to be by default, so this input redirection may just be re-enforcing the situation as it is.

The `/dev/ttyO0` device is the direct representation of the UART that is connected to your terminal program on the other computer. When you read from it, you get *only what you are typing into the terminal program*: there is no way to read back any output that was previously sent into it. And anything written into it goes directly to the terminal program at the end of the serial cable.

The Unix command line on a serial port normally works on a *remote echo* principle: in order to see what you are writing on the terminal program, the TTY driver on the embedded system must send a copy of every character you type right back to the terminal program. This behavior is not symmetric: the terminal program will not be also sending back a copy of anything it receives over the serial port connection.

The TTY driver is a complicated thing, because Unix heritage requires it to be capable of doing a lot of things - the remote echo feature is just one of them.

When you use `stty raw`, you're effectively *switching off all the normally-helpful features of the TTY driver*, including the remote echo feature. So, from that point onwards, unless something explicitly reads from `/dev/ttyS0` and writes it immediately right back into it, you won't see what you are writing on the terminal program.

Once the `stty raw` command has exited, any input from the terminal program will go into the `cat` command, which would just pass it into its standard output as-is when invoked with no parameters. But its standard output has now been redirected into a file, `received.txt`. So what happens is that *only what you're typing on the terminal program gets written into the file* until the `cat` command ends - and it only ends when it gets the end-of-file character (typically <kbd>Control+D</kbd>).

(Because of whatever buffering might be done by the shell doing the redirection, there might be no output into the `received.txt` file unless you end your typing with the end-of-file character, and/or type more than one line of text.)

So, other than switching off the TTY driver features, the `(stty raw; cat > received.txt) < /dev/ttyO0` on the embedded system does nothing at all to capture any *output* that is being written into `/dev/ttyO0`. The only use for this command would be when you're troubleshooting the *serial port connection*: if you are suspicious that your terminal program is somehow mangling the characters you're sending out, this is the way to capture whatever the terminal program is sending to the embedded device in its most raw form.

---

If you want to record **absolutely everything** that happens over the UART connection, including e.g. kernel panic messages, then the best way to do it would probably be to tell your terminal program on the other computer to log all the traffic. Many terminal programs have this feature built-in.

This is because if something is going wrong with the kernel, it might not be actually possible to write anything into a disk file any more. It's much simpler to just send the error message text out of an UART and trust that whoever is receiving it will catch it.

Comment: Dear telcoM, thank you for the detailed answer. May be I missed your point, but you didn't recommend me what to do and didn't say that ths is impossible...:-)        
What I want is simple: all I see on the PC connected to the UART to be stored in a file on the embedded device. This will allow me to analyse possible fails. I don't type a thing in the 'field" - nobody is there. Just kernels and program's outputs are sent to console by kernel and programs.

Comment: I understand that this is TTY output going to the serial line, but I don't believe that there is no way to copy it somehow to somewhere. Redirecting output(s) from specific program(s)/daemons/etc is obvious, but besides it is strange to run on each and redirect, this is also not sufficient, as kernel messages (from drivers, for example) are missing.

Comment: I am trying to play with /dev/vcs but no success yet.

Comment: The kernel messages may come from an entirely different output routine: instead of the full TTY driver, the panic routine just pushes the error message directly out of the physical UART. When the system is panicing, **you might no longer have the ability to write into files:** perhaps the panic was because the disk or filesystem driver has detected a fatal error? To capture truly **everything**, including kernel panic messages, you really need to look at external solutions, of which the easiest is to use the logging capability of the terminal program at the other end of the serial link.

Comment: `/dev/vcs` gives you only the way to peek into virtual consoles, which are a feature of the GPU-based console driver only: on serial consoles, you don't have that unless you run something like `screen` or `tmux` for similar functionality. To get **everything from userspace**, `ttysnoop` might be a solution; but the kernel messages to the serial console can bypass it.

Comment: Well, i am not so ambitious...:-) I understand that kernel panic cannot be stored. And this is not the case. But, let's say for example "segmentation fault" is definitely the case. Driver's messages about some problems are too.

Comment: tmux and ttysnoop are unfamiliar to me! Thank you very much - going to study!!

Comment: Note that on modern kernels, the basic "segmentation fault" message is emitted to `stderr`, but the kernel may also emit a kernel-level message (`process[PID]: segfault at <memory address> <stack pointer> error <number> in <filename>[address]`). If you see those on the serial line, it's because kernel is sending them to `/dev/console` - which on your system maps to the same UART as `/dev/ttyO0` but is otherwise separate from `ttyO0`. If you are after segfaults, you should consider *enabling core dumps* - they capture the full state of the application at the time of segfault.

Answer (score 0):

Try using picocom instead of console=/dev/ttyS0. There are other tools but picocom sounds the easiest.

If you use one of these tools you can use a pipe and tee on the output.

```
picocom /dev/ttyS0 -b 115200 -l | tee my.log
```

https://askubuntu.com/q/1010232

Comment: Please use syntax for formatting code

Comment: i am afraid this is not work as picocom will work in the opposite direction - system output sent by Linux to console is an output for picocom, IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

Try https://tio.github.io - it supports logging to file. For example:

```
tio /dev/ttyS0 --log --log-file my-log.txt
```

Or

```
tio /dev/ttyS0 --log
```

Which logs serial output to file with auto-generated filename such as `tio_ttyS0_2022-09-14T08:56:09.log`

Comment: Thanks, Martin, but you missed the main point - it is an embedded system and I need to store serial output for analysis in the field, when there is no PC connected.