# How do I make a secondary readable text file next to the rawlog file, like it would appear when you type in "savelog" manually in terminal?

Tags: debian, terminal, output

The question comes from this question here: [Save all the terminal output to a file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/200637/save-all-the-terminal-output-to-a-file/), specifically this post: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/323920/478293 but I can't post a comment on there asking this since I need 50 reputation and direct messaging the editor or poster seems non-existent on this site....

Ok, so I've tried adding some lines from the savelog block to the smart script block to make this work for myself but I don't know if I did it right... It says the rawlog file doesn't exist, which I guess is kinda true since it's trying to convert a rawlog file that doesn't yet exist, how do I make it so that it wait till it exists?

I'm guessing I need an if else statement somewhere in there but not sure what to use to tell it to wait until the file is created and *then* convert and have a readable text file copy of it, along with the original rawlog file, in the same directory automatically without needing to invoke the savelog command in terminal. Any ideas?

My code:

```
# Execute "script" command just once
smart_script(){
    # if there's no SCRIPT_LOG_FILE exported yet
    if [ -z "$SCRIPT_LOG_FILE" ]; then
        # make folder paths
        logdirparent=~/Terminal_typescripts
        logdirraw=raw/$(date +%F)
        logdir=$logdirparent/$logdirraw
        logfile=$logdir/$(date +%F_%T).$$.rawlog
        txtfile=$logdir/$(date +%F_%T).$$'.txt'

        # if no folder exist - make one
        if [ ! -d $logdir ]; then
            mkdir -p $logdir
        fi

        export SCRIPT_LOG_FILE=$logfile
        export SCRIPT_LOG_PARENT_FOLDER=$logdirparent

        # make .rawlog readable and save it to .txt file
        cat $SCRIPT_LOG_FILE | perl -pe 's/\e([^\[\]]|\[.*?[a-zA-Z]|\].*?\a)//g' | col -b > $txtfile

        # quiet output if no args are passed
        if [ ! -z "$1" ]; then
            script -f $logfile
            script -f $txtfile
        else
            script -f -q $logfile
            script -f -q $txtfile
        fi

        exit
    fi
}

# Start logging into new file
alias startnewlog='unset SCRIPT_LOG_FILE && smart_script -v'

# Manually saves current log file: $ savelog logname
savelog(){
    # make folder path
    manualdir=$SCRIPT_LOG_PARENT_FOLDER/manual
    # if no folder exists - make one
    if [ ! -d $manualdir ]; then
        mkdir -p $manualdir
    fi
    # make log name
    logname=${SCRIPT_LOG_FILE##*/}
    logname=${logname%.*}
    # add user logname if passed as argument
    if [ ! -z $1 ]; then
        logname=$logname'_'$1
    fi
    # make filepaths
    txtfile=$manualdir/$logname'.txt'
    rawfile=$manualdir/$logname'.rawlog'
    # make .rawlog readable and save it to .txt file
    cat $SCRIPT_LOG_FILE | perl -pe 's/\e([^\[\]]|\[.*?[a-zA-Z]|\].*?\a)//g' | col -b > $txtfile
    # copy corresponding .rawfile
    cp $SCRIPT_LOG_FILE $rawfile
    printf 'Saved logs:\n    '$txtfile'\n    '$rawfile'\n'
}
```

Comment: Your code is just functions which are added to .bashrc, but I had to read the links to figure hat out. It's fine to reference other resources, but questions should be readable without them. I can't quite see what's going on here. Maybe if you add
`shopt -s -o xtrace  # debug`
`shopt -s -o verbose  # debug`
to the top of your functions as two separate lines, the additional output will show you what's wrong.