# How can I log everything that appears on the screen?

Tags: bash, shell-script, ubuntu

I want to log everything that appears on the screen. It's supposed to be something like a history file:
I've made something like that but it doesn't work. I can't see what script is doing.

```
exec > output.txt 2>&1

echo "Hello"
echo "Alice"
echo "put something"
read input
echo $input
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: `script &> output.log` ? Your `exec` redirect makes no sense if that's exactly what you're running. Read `man exec` for more details.

Comment: Thank for suggestion. I must put the redirection in file of script. I don't have big experience in bash so I copy it from stackover. Thank for suggestion.

Comment: Is this only for things that are shown in the terminal or do you want everything that appears "in the screen" including GUI? Are you just looking for this: [Save all the terminal output to a file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/200637)

Comment: Not at all. My script save logs to a file but I don't see the script running on the screen :(. I need to do something in this script  to save logs in the file.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found any useful information. I made something what is very ugly for me:

```
'''  echo "Hello"|&tee -a log.txt
     echo "Alice"|&tee -a log.txt
     echo "put something"|&tee -a log.txt
     read input
     echo &input|&tee -a log.txt

'''
```

> Blockquote

Thank you for your help.